# MBString Segfault with apache2 ubuntu 18.04 Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, php7, symfony

I am working on a script API with Laravel 5.7. When I try and run a command on the API, I get the following segfault

> segfault at 7ffc466e9ee8 ip 00007f2adb4144ed sp 00007ffc466e9ef0 error
>   6 in mbstring.so[7f2adb3a7000+176000]

The error I am getting from Laravel is:

> [2019-01-25 23:19:32][3] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessVideo
>
> Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessSignaledException  : The
>   process has been signaled with signal "11".
>
> at /var/www/api/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:426
>       422|             usleep(1000);
>       423|         }
>       424|
>       425|         if ($this->processInformation['signaled'] && $this->processInformation['termsig'] !== $this->latestSignal) {
>
> > 426|             throw new ProcessSignaledException($this);
> >         427|         }
> >         428|
> >         429|         return $this->exitcode;
> >         430|     }
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   Symfony\Component\Process\Process::wait()
>         /var/www/api/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:235
>
> 2   Symfony\Component\Process\Process::run(Object(Closure))
>         /var/www/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Listener.php:175

Any thoughts - I'm running out of sight on the problem

Comment: Is the segfault identical every time, or is it different?

Comment: It is the same each time.

kernel: [1033464.158706] php7.2[26556]: segfault at 7ffe70802dd8 ip 00007ff3960634ed sp 00007ffe70802de0 error 6 in mbstring.so[7ff395ff6000+176000]

Comment: The file is most probably corrupt. Try reinstalling the package.

Comment: Been there done that - even tried rolling back to 7.1 - This error is also happening on both dev and beta boxes.

Comment: A bug in PHP, then?

Comment: I am starting to think this is completely out of scope from this document. I need to reevaluate the issue.